# How sort using stream() in Java 8, two floats subtraction?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I have a simple object User, with fields like below:

```
class User {
    int id; float size, size2; String username, nickname;

[...]
public float getPercentage() {
             return (size - size2); //
         }
}
```

I try to use [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) from java 8, but without result. I try to sort by value which is calculated like this: `(size - size2)`. But result is wrong, for this objects. First I create a list:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1.5f));
users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1.2f));
users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1f));
users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1.6f));
users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1.3f));
```

My comparator looks like this:

```
Comparator<User> bySizeDifferent = Comparator.comparing(user -> user.getPercentage());
```

And the I use comparator and display result:

```
users.stream().sorted(bySizeDifferent).forEach(System.out::println);
```

After sort result looks like this (the last column is result of subtraction):

```
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.5-diff- 0.0- = 0.0
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.2-diff- 0.2999999523162842- = 0.29999995
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.0-diff- 0.5- = 0.5
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.6-diff- -0.10000002384185791- = -0.100000024
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.3-diff- 0.20000004768371582- = 0.20000005
```

To see this output method toString() is overrided:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " - " + username + "-" + nickname + "-" + size + "-" + size2 + "-diff- " + diff + "- = " + getPercentage();
    }
```

Any advice how solve this?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Agreed - I note the output is the same order as the input. Are you sure you're actually sorting anything at all? Are you even using the `Comparator`? We have no way to tell.

Comment: I edited question, hope that now it is more understandable.

Comment: You might need `forEachOrdered` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: @Alex no, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what a short, complete program looks like. It puts together all the bits and pieces you provided above, and it works, and sorts as expected. I don't know what you're doing differently, because you never actually provided a short complete program, but this works:

```
package com.example.dcsohl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Comparator8 {

    public static class User {
        int id; float size, size2; String username, nickname;

        public User(int id, String name, String nick, float size, float size2) {
            this.id = id;
            this.username = name;
            this.nickname = nick;
            this.size = size;
            this.size2 = size2;
        }

        public float getPercentage() {
            return (size - size2);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return id + " - " + username + "-" + nickname + "-" + size + "-" + size2 + "-diff- " + getPercentage();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1.5f));
        users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1.2f));
        users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1f));
        users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1.6f));
        users.add(new User(1, "User","nickname", 1.5f, 1.3f));

        Comparator<User> bySizeDifferent = Comparator.comparing(user -> user.getPercentage());

        users.stream().sorted(bySizeDifferent).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Here's the output:

```
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.6-diff- -0.100000024
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.5-diff- 0.0
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.3-diff- 0.20000005
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.2-diff- 0.29999995
1 - User-nickname-1.5-1.0-diff- 0.5
```

Comment: Yeah, I got the same result. He must have something else going on in part of the code that isn't shown.

Comment: Exactly. I had to provide the `User` constructor, for example ... for all I know, he's giving `size` and `size2` the same value by accident. And his `toString()` mentioned a variable, `diff`, that wasn't mentioned anywhere else. I ignored it in my code, but who knows what it does in the OP's code?